# ZeroClipboard after jquery load

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

I have a page with ZeroClipboard that works and I can copy a text.
In the same website the same page it can be load in another page with jquery load(). The problem is that when the page is loaded the copy button don't works. Tryed to build the ZeroClipboard with and without html and body tags. Tryed to use jquery html('') and works. The 2 pages are using the same jquery version.

```
<script src="<?=base_url()?>public/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>public/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('<?=base_url()?>public/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf');

var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
clip.addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
  clip.setText(document.getElementById('copiami').value);
});

clip.addEventListener('complete',function(client,text) {
  alert('copiato:\n\n' + text);
});

clip.glue('copiatesto');
</script>
```

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle or code sample to play around with?